# Error using put-group-policy with cli-input-json

Tags: json, amazon-iam, aws-cli

i am trying to create a policy for group by using cli-input-json providing json as input to the cli command.
The command is

```
aws iam put-group-policy --cli-input-json file://D:\\json\\demo\\json
grpPolicy_testpolicy1.json
```

which gives following error

```
A client error (MalformedPolicyDocument) occurred when calling the PutGroupPolicy operation: The policy is not in the valid JSON format.
```

**The content of json file at D:\json\demo\json
grpPolicy_testpolicy1.json is**

```
{
    "GroupName": "testgroup11",
    "PolicyName": "testpolicy11",
    "PolicyDocument": "file://D:\\json\\policypermission.txt"
}
```

**The content of policy document file at D:\json\
policypermission.txt is**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "uploadandgetfromS3",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:CreateBucket",
                "s3:CreateObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:PutBucketAcl",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "rds:DescribeDBLogFiles",
                "rds:DownloadDbLogFilePortion"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

i have verified all the json files for the validity of json, still aws cli says that the policy document is malformed.
i have also created and attached the above said policy by using normal cli command to confirm the validity of the policy document and that has worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{
    "GroupName": "testgroup11",
    "PolicyName": "testpolicy11",
    "PolicyDocument": "file://D:\\json\\policypermission.txt"
}
```

While this would make sense conceptually, I think the [AWS Command Line Interface (AWS CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) doesn't support inline/nested references to URLs like `file://` here, rather only as a command line argument, e.g.:

```
aws iam put-group-policy --cli-input-json file://D:\\json\\demo\\json \
  grpPolicy_testpolicy1.json --policy-document file://D:\\json\\policypermission.txt
```

This works, because command line arguments take precedence over those specified as [CLI Input JSON Parameters](http://Generate%20CLI%20Skeleton%20and%20CLI%20Input%20JSON%20Parameter). However, once you do not specify the overriding `--policy-document`, the JSON parser trips over the inline `PolicyDocument` element, where it expects an inline JSON object but encounters the URL `file://D:\\json\\policypermission.txt` instead.

Comment: not the exact solution i was looking for , but yes that helped me without making any serious changes and most importantly provided different perspective to the problem, thnks :)